# user defined variables in a function in r

Tags: r, variables, regression, formula

I am trying to do a generic function to construct a formula for lineal regression. I want that the function create the formula either

- using user defined variables or,
- using all the variables present in the dataframe.

I can create the formula using all the variables present in the dataframe but my problem is when I try to get the user defined variables, I do not know exactly how to get the variables to later use them to create the formula.

The function that I have until now is this:

```
lmformula <- function (data, IndepVariable = character, VariableList = TRUE){
  if (VariableList) {
newlist <- list()
newlist <-  # Here is where I do not exactly what to do to extract the variables defined by user
DependVariables <- newlist
f <- as.formula(paste(IndepVariable, "~", paste((DependVariables), collapse = '+')))
 }else {
names(data) <- make.names(colnames(data))
DependVariables <- names(data)[!colnames(data)%in% IndepVariable]
f <- as.formula(paste(IndepVariable,"~", paste((DependVariables), collapse = '+')))
return (f)
 }
}
```

Please any hint will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Something like `f <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ .", dependentVariable)); lm(f, data = data[, Predictors])`. Note that in regression on the LHS is the dependent variable and on the RHS the predictors/independent variables.

Comment: my problem is with `DependVariables`. How do I get the variables given by the user? What I want is to stock in `DependVariables` the list of variables typed by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that changes is how you get the independent variables

If the user specifies them, then use that character vector **directly**

Else, you have to to take all the variables other than the dependent variable(which you are already doing)

Note : As Roland mentioned, the formula is like dependentVariable ~ independentVariable1 + independentVariable2 + independentVariable3

```
# creating mock data
data <- data.frame(col1 = numeric(0), col2 = numeric(0), col3 = numeric(0), col4 = numeric(0))

# the function
lmformula <- function (data, DepVariable, IndepVariable, VariableList = TRUE) {
  if (!VariableList) {
    IndepVariable <- names(data)[!names(data) %in% DepVariable]
  }
  f <- as.formula(paste(DepVariable,"~", paste(IndepVariable, collapse = '+')))
  return (f)
}

# working examples
lmformula(data = data, DepVariable = "col1", VariableList = FALSE)
lmformula(data = data, DepVariable = "col1", IndepVariable = c("col2", "col3"), VariableList = TRUE)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeap!  very useful Thanks for the observation, I did not realized that I was using wrong the dependent variable

Comment: The built-in `reformulate()` function is desired to turn character column names into a formula. `f<-reformulate(IndepVariable, DepVariable)`

Comment: And if you want to model one variable on all others in a data.frame, then you can use the formula `resp~.` (the period stands for everything else -- no need to list them all explicitly).